# Will inked terrain in the campaign hub stay inked if I return to Splatsville?

Tags: splatoon-3

I've inked a large portion of the floor in the first hub area of the campaign. If I leave the campaign by returning to Splatsville, will the hub area still be covered in ink when I come back?

[image: inked hub]

Comment: You can easily discover it by yourself. But if it's like Splatoon 2, no, the ink will disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The map resets when you leave to return to splatville.